# How to get a particular cell from MySQL table using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, cell

I'm having a problem with getting a specific cell from database.

Here is what I've got:

[image]

So, how do I get only that last cell with URL using PHP and MySQL?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28SQL%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');

if (!$conn) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db('database');

$result = mysql_query('select URL from table');

if (!$result) {
    die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
}

echo mysql_result($result, 0); // outputs

mysql_close($conn);

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should add an auto-increment column named ID to your table.
So then you can do:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

PD: This will return the last cell added to your table. If it's not what you want please give more information.